# the elements are cleared after the code runs instead of staying. Any ideas?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
// stores books
let myLibrary = [];
// the constructor...
function Book(title, author, pages, read, imageURL) {
  this.title = title;
  this.author = author;
  this.pages = pages;
  this.read = read;
  this.imageURL = imageURL;
}
//Function to add new books to the array
function addBookToLibrary(title, author, pages, read, imageURL) {
  let book = new Book(title, author, pages, read, imageURL);
  myLibrary.push(book);
  console.log(myLibrary[0]);
  displayBooksOnPage();
}

//function to display cards in the array
function displayBooksOnPage() {
  const books = document.querySelector(".cards");

  //counter used in the content loop
  let counter = 0;

  //removes previous card before reiteration
  //Create the card for each book in array
  myLibrary.forEach((myLibrary) => {
    const card = document.createElement("div");
    card.classList.add("card");
    books.append(card);

    //Adds all the content into the card
    for (let key in myLibrary) {
      console.log("a");
      if (counter <= 0) {
        const titleHeader = document.createElement("h5");
        titleHeader.textContent = `${myLibrary[key]}`;
        titleHeader.classList.add("card-title");
        card.appendChild(titleHeader);
        counter = 1;
      } else if (counter < 2) {
        const cardAuthor = document.createElement("p");
        cardAuthor.textContent = `${myLibrary[key]}`;
        cardAuthor.classList.add("card-author");
        card.appendChild(cardAuthor);
        counter = 2;
      } else if (counter < 3) {
        const cardPages = document.createElement("p");
        cardPages.textContent = `${myLibrary[key]}`;
        cardPages.classList.add("card-pages");
        card.appendChild(cardPages);
        counter = 3;
      } else if (counter < 4) {
        const readContainer = document.createElement("div");
        readContainer.classList.add("read");
        card.appendChild(readContainer);
        const readElement = document.createElement("p");
        readElement.textContent = `${myLibrary[key]}`;
        readElement.classList.add("card-read");
        readContainer.append(readElement);
        counter = 4;
      } else if (counter < 5) {
        const imageContainer = document.createElement("div");
        imageContainer.classList.add("book-image-container");
        card.appendChild(imageContainer);
        const bookImage = document.createElement("img");
        bookImage.src = `${myLibrary[key]}`;
        bookImage.classList.add("book-image");
        imageContainer.append(bookImage);
        const editContainer = document.createElement("div");
        editContainer.classList.add("edit-container");
        card.appendChild(editContainer);
        const editBtn = document.createElement("button");
        editBtn.innerText = "Edit";
        editBtn.classList.add("edit");
        editContainer.append(editBtn);
        const deleteContainer = document.createElement("div");
        deleteContainer.classList.add("delete-container");
        card.appendChild(deleteContainer);
        const deleteBtn = document.createElement("button");
        deleteBtn.innerText = "Delete";
        deleteBtn.classList.add("delete");
        deleteContainer.append(deleteBtn);
      }
    }

    function resetCounter() {
      counter = 0;
    }
    resetCounter();
  });
}

//New book button
const newBookBtn = document.getElementById("newBookBtn");
newBookBtn.addEventListener("click", displayForm);

//Displays the new book form
function displayForm() {
  document.getElementById("formContainer").style.display = "";
}

//eventlistener on form to submit data
const submitBtn = document.querySelector(".submit-button");
submitBtn.addEventListener("click", intakeFormData);

//transform form data to variables
function intakeFormData() {
  let title = document.getElementById("Title").value;
  let author = document.getElementById("Author").value;
  let pages = document.getElementById("Pages").value;
  let read = document.getElementById("Read").value;
  let imageURL = document.getElementById("imageURL").value;

  addBookToLibrary(title, author, pages, read, imageURL);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" defer></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resetcss.css" />
  <title>Sign-Up Form</title>
</head>

<body id="body">
  <div class="sideBar">
    <div class="menuItem">
      <img class="white dashIcon" src="./images/view-dashboard-variant-outline.png" alt="" />
      <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="menuItem">
      <img class="white" src="./images/home.png" alt="" />
      <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="menuItem">
      <img class="white" src="./images/account.png" alt="" />
      <h1>Profile</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="menuItem">
      <img class="white" src="./images/message.png" alt="" />
      <h1>Messages</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="menuItem">
      <img class="white" src="./images/clock.png" alt="" />
      <h1>History</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="menuItem">
      <img class="white" src="./images/note-multiple.png" alt="" />
      <h1>Tasks</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="menuItem">
      <img class="white" src="./images/account-group.png" alt="" />
      <h1>Communities</h1>
    </div>
    <!--Needs extra spacing-->
    <div class="menuItem">
      <img class="white" src="./images/cog.png" alt="" />
      <h1>Settings</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="menuItem">
      <img class="white" src="./images/help-circle.png" alt="" />
      <h1>Support</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="menuItem">
      <img class="white" src="./images/shield-check-outline.png" alt="" />
      <h1>Privacy</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header">
    <!--Top section-->
    <div class="topHeader">
      <div class="search">
        <div class="menuItem">
          <img src="./images/magnify.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="search" />
      </div>
      <div class="account">
        <div class="menuIcon">
          <img src="./images/bell.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <img class="avatar" src="./images/avatar.jpg" alt="" />
        <p class="name">Benjamin Gill</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Bottom section-->
    <div class="bottomHeader">
      <div class="profile">
        <img class="avatar" src="./images/avatar.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="profile-name">
          <p class="greeting">Hi there,</p>
          <p class="name">
            Benjamin Gill <span class="username">(@Bgill)</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button id="newBookBtn" class="btn">New Book</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="projects">
      <h3>Your Books:</h3>
      <div class="cards">
        <div class="card">
          <h5 class="card-title">The Hobbit</h5>
          <p class="card-author">by: J.R.R. Tolken</p>
          <p class="card-pages">345 pages</p>
          <div class="read">
            <p class="card-read">Not yet read</p>
          </div>
          <div class="book-image-container">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a9/The_Hobbit_trilogy_dvd_cover.jpg/220px-The_Hobbit_trilogy_dvd_cover.jpg" alt="" class="book-image" />
          </div>
          <div class="edit-container">
            <button class="edit">Edit</button>
          </div>
          <div class="delete-container">
            <button class="delete">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="formContainer" class="cards" style="display: none">
          <form id="newBookForm" class="card">
            <input type="text" name="Title" id="Title" class="card-title" placeholder="Book Title..." />
            <input type="text" name="Author" id="Author" placeholder="Author Name..." class="card-author" />
            <input type="number" name="Pages" id="Pages" placeholder="Amount of Pages..." class="card-pages" />
            <input type="text" name="Read" id="Read" placeholder="Have you read this?" class="read" />
            <input type="text" name="imageURL" id="imageURL" placeholder="Enter image URL..." class="book-image-container" />
            <div class="edit-container">
              <button type="reset" class="reset-button edit">
                  Reset Form
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="delete-container">
              <button type="submit" class="submit-button delete">
                  Sumbit to Library
                </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

My main issue is in Javascript. It takes the intakeFormData and then goes through the add newBookToLibrary. Once there it runs the displayBooksOnPage and creates the new card by adding elements to the dom. Once all the elements are added, it finishes at the intakeFormData and then calls the myLibrary. Once it calls the myLibrary it just removes all the newly added elements.

I've looked at chrome dev tools and followed it through. It completed everything correctly. But once it is towards the end it calls the first two variables as when the page loads and it clears everything that was added.

Answer (score 1):

myLibrary is a global variables. Please change it to variabile locale try again.

`function addBookToLibrary`  add a return value. Call it in the `function displayBooksOnPage`.

Answer (score 1):

I added two things to your `intakeFormData()` function:

- an `ev.preventDefault()` to suppress the actual submission of the form and the opening of an empty page
- and `toggleDisplay()` to hide the form after pressing the "Sumbit to Library" button.

`toggleDisplay()` replaces your original `displayForm()` function.

My changes will prevent the page and its content from disappearing. I haven't fully understood what you are doing in `displayBooksOnPage()` but I am sure there are ways of doing the same job in a much simpler way.

```js
// stores books
let myLibrary = [];
// the constructor...
function Book(title, author, pages, read, imageURL) {
  this.title = title;
  this.author = author;
  this.pages = pages;
  this.read = read;
  this.imageURL = imageURL;
}
//Function to add new books to the array
function addBookToLibrary(title, author, pages, read, imageURL) {
  let book = new Book(title, author, pages, read, imageURL);
  myLibrary.push(book);
  console.log(myLibrary[0]);
  displayBooksOnPage();
}

//function to display cards in the array
function displayBooksOnPage() {
  const books = document.querySelector(".cards");

  //counter used in the content loop
  let counter = 0;

  //removes previous card before reiteration
  //Create the card for each book in array
  myLibrary.forEach((myLibrary) => {
    const card = document.createElement("div");
    card.classList.add("card");
    books.append(card);

    //Adds all the content into the card
    for (let key in myLibrary) {
      console.log("a");
      if (counter <= 0) {
        const titleHeader = document.createElement("h5");
        titleHeader.textContent = `${myLibrary[key]}`;
        titleHeader.classList.add("card-title");
        card.appendChild(titleHeader);
        counter = 1;
      } else if (counter < 2) {
        const cardAuthor = document.createElement("p");
        cardAuthor.textContent = `${myLibrary[key]}`;
        cardAuthor.classList.add("card-author");
        card.appendChild(cardAuthor);
        counter = 2;
      } else if (counter < 3) {
        const cardPages = document.createElement("p");
        cardPages.textContent = `${myLibrary[key]}`;
        cardPages.classList.add("card-pages");
        card.appendChild(cardPages);
        counter = 3;
      } else if (counter < 4) {
        const readContainer = document.createElement("div");
        readContainer.classList.add("read");
        card.appendChild(readContainer);
        const readElement = document.createElement("p");
        readElement.textContent = `${myLibrary[key]}`;
        readElement.classList.add("card-read");
        readContainer.append(readElement);
        counter = 4;
      } else if (counter < 5) {
        const imageContainer = document.createElement("div");
        imageContainer.classList.add("book-image-container");
        card.appendChild(imageContainer);
        const bookImage = document.createElement("img");
        bookImage.src = `${myLibrary[key]}`;
        bookImage.classList.add("book-image");
        imageContainer.append(bookImage);
        const editContainer = document.createElement("div");
        editContainer.classList.add("edit-container");
        card.appendChild(editContainer);
        const editBtn = document.createElement("button");
        editBtn.innerText = "Edit";
        editBtn.classList.add("edit");
        editContainer.append(editBtn);
        const deleteContainer = document.createElement("div");
        deleteContainer.classList.add("delete-container");
        card.appendChild(deleteContainer);
        const deleteBtn = document.createElement("button");
        deleteBtn.innerText = "Delete";
        deleteBtn.classList.add("delete");
        deleteContainer.append(deleteBtn);
      }
    }

    function resetCounter() {
      counter = 0;
    }
    resetCounter();
  });
}

//New book button
const newBookBtn = document.getElementById("newBookBtn");
newBookBtn.addEventListener("click", toggleForm);

//Displays the new book form
function toggleForm() {
  const fstyle=document.getElementById("formContainer").style;
  fstyle.display=fstyle.display==""?"none":"";
}

//eventlistener on form to submit data
const submitBtn = document.querySelector(".submit-button");
submitBtn.addEventListener("click", intakeFormData);

//transform form data to variables
function intakeFormData(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  toggleForm();
  let title = document.getElementById("Title").value;
  let author = document.getElementById("Author").value;
  let pages = document.getElementById("Pages").value;
  let read = document.getElementById("Read").value;
  let imageURL = document.getElementById("imageURL").value;

  addBookToLibrary(title, author, pages, read, imageURL);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" defer></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resetcss.css" />
  <title>Sign-Up Form</title>
</head>

<body id="body">
  <div class="sideBar">
    <div class="menuItem">
      <img class="white dashIcon" src="./images/view-dashboard-variant-outline.png" alt="" />
      <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="menuItem">
      <img class="white" src="./images/home.png" alt="" />
      <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="menuItem">
      <img class="white" src="./images/account.png" alt="" />
      <h1>Profile</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="menuItem">
      <img class="white" src="./images/message.png" alt="" />
      <h1>Messages</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="menuItem">
      <img class="white" src="./images/clock.png" alt="" />
      <h1>History</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="menuItem">
      <img class="white" src="./images/note-multiple.png" alt="" />
      <h1>Tasks</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="menuItem">
      <img class="white" src="./images/account-group.png" alt="" />
      <h1>Communities</h1>
    </div>
    <!--Needs extra spacing-->
    <div class="menuItem">
      <img class="white" src="./images/cog.png" alt="" />
      <h1>Settings</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="menuItem">
      <img class="white" src="./images/help-circle.png" alt="" />
      <h1>Support</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="menuItem">
      <img class="white" src="./images/shield-check-outline.png" alt="" />
      <h1>Privacy</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header">
    <!--Top section-->
    <div class="topHeader">
      <div class="search">
        <div class="menuItem">
          <img src="./images/magnify.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="search" />
      </div>
      <div class="account">
        <div class="menuIcon">
          <img src="./images/bell.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <img class="avatar" src="./images/avatar.jpg" alt="" />
        <p class="name">Benjamin Gill</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Bottom section-->
    <div class="bottomHeader">
      <div class="profile">
        <img class="avatar" src="./images/avatar.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="profile-name">
          <p class="greeting">Hi there,</p>
          <p class="name">
            Benjamin Gill <span class="username">(@Bgill)</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button id="newBookBtn" class="btn">New Book</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="projects">
      <h3>Your Books:</h3>
      <div class="cards">
        <div class="card">
          <h5 class="card-title">The Hobbit</h5>
          <p class="card-author">by: J.R.R. Tolken</p>
          <p class="card-pages">345 pages</p>
          <div class="read">
            <p class="card-read">Not yet read</p>
          </div>
          <div class="book-image-container">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a9/The_Hobbit_trilogy_dvd_cover.jpg/220px-The_Hobbit_trilogy_dvd_cover.jpg" alt="" class="book-image" />
          </div>
          <div class="edit-container">
            <button class="edit">Edit</button>
          </div>
          <div class="delete-container">
            <button class="delete">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="formContainer" class="cards" style="display: none">
          <form id="newBookForm" class="card">
            <input type="text" name="Title" id="Title" class="card-title" placeholder="Book Title..." />
            <input type="text" name="Author" id="Author" placeholder="Author Name..." class="card-author" />
            <input type="number" name="Pages" id="Pages" placeholder="Amount of Pages..." class="card-pages" />
            <input type="text" name="Read" id="Read" placeholder="Have you read this?" class="read" />
            <input type="text" name="imageURL" id="imageURL" placeholder="Enter image URL..." class="book-image-container" />
            <div class="edit-container">
              <button type="reset" class="reset-button edit">
                  Reset Form
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="delete-container">
              <button type="submit" class="submit-button delete">
                  Sumbit to Library
                </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! The display books is basically just dom manipulation adding elements and classes to the card so everything is positioned correctly. I’ll look into refactoring it.

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you again. I tested this out and it solves the exact problem I had.